# Echoing a PHP SQL query to a webpage

Tags: php, sql

I'm trying to get a total amount for a list of sales using an SQL statement in PHP, I already have the SQL statement but I'm not sure how to get the results of the query onto the webpage, I'm planning on putting it in the second PHP tag after the table.

```
        $result = mysqli_query($dbc,$query);
            echo "<p>Customers on file = " .mysqli_num_rows($result). "</p>";
            while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)) {
                echo "<tr>";
                echo "<td>" .$row[0]. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['last_name']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['Customer_id']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['3']. "</td>";
                echo "<td>" .$row['4']. ", " .$row['5']. " " .$row['6']. "</td>";
                echo "<td align='right'>$" .number_format($row['credit_limit']). "</td>";
                echo "<td align='right'>" .$row['salescnt']. "</td>";
                echo "<td align='right'>" .number_format($row['salestot'],2). "</td>";
                echo "<tr>";
                
            }
            
        ?>
        </table>
        <?php 
        $query = "SELECT sum(total) AS totsales FROM sales_order";
        
        echo "<p>Total of all sales = " </p>" ?>
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: You do it the same way as the first query. Call `mysqli_query()`, call `$row = mysqli_fetch_array()` to get the results, then `echo $row[0];`

Comment: I don't see how you knew how to display the table, but can't figure out how to display the result of the second query.